# Understanding of C# await operator

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I just have some basic understanding of C#'s asynchronous programming. As I understand, this code

```
statement1;
await statement2();
statement3;
statement4;
```

should logically be equivalent to

```
statement1;
var awaiter = statement2().GetAwaiter();
awaiter.OnCompletion(() => {
    awaiter.GetResult();
    statement3;
    statement4;
});
```

So if there is an `await` statement in the code, all the following statements will only start to execute after the awaited task completed. This seems just like synchronous code. The document states that the `await` statement will cause the execution return to the caller and resume after the awaited task completes. But I can't fully understand how it works in the following example.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await DoSomething2(); // <------- B
            Console.WriteLine("Test!"); // <------- C
            Console.ReadKey(); // <------- D
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething2"); 
            var i = await DoSomething(); // <------ A
            Console.WriteLine("End DoSomething2");
        }

        public static async Task<int> DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething1");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Before returning from DoSomething1");
            return 88;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Start DoSomething2
Start DoSomething1
Before returning from DoSomething1
End DoSomething2
Test!
```

Let's take statement A for example. Here it's awaiting `DoSomething()`. While awaiting it, the execution logic returns from `DoSomething2()` and goes back to B. Here as I understand, the execution should go on to execute statement C and D while awaiting `DoSomething2()` (statement B). But the result shows that the string `"Test!"` only be printed at the end of the program. Why this happens? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "Here as I understand, the execution should go on to execute statement C and D while awaiting DoSomething2()" - no, it would only execute C & D *after* B has been successfully awaited (whether that is synchronous or asynchronous) - kinda like in your first example (although that isn't *quite* how it actually gets implemented; the machinery is more ... involved)

Comment: in a nutshell : the `await` does exactly what what word 'await' means : it waits until the `Task` returns before going on with the rest of the code. It means the code written _looks_ synchronous. But it is actually non-blocking, for instance if executed on the UI thread, other operations like refresh the window can still be performed because the thread can be 'released' if the Task is taking much time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catch is that your  `Main` returns `Task`, so it is also fully `async` and will be "stopped". And your execution order will look like this:

1. `Main()` starts
2. Main gets to the `await` operator and creates a `Task` with the rest of the method. It looks as if the `Main()` has stopped, waiting for the `await` result
3. `DoSomething2()` starts and writes to the console "Start DoSomething2"
4. It gets to the next `await` operator and creates another `Task` with the rest of the `DoSomething()` method
5. `DoSomething()` starts
6. It writes to the console "Start DoSomething1"
7. Gets to the `awat` operator and creates a `Task` with the rest of the `DoSomething()` method, waiting for a delay.
8. After this `Task` is completed (after a delay) `DoSomething()` writes "Before returning from DoSomething1" to console and returns 88.
9. The `Task`, created in `DoSomething2()` completes the rest of the method (assigns 88 to `i` and writes "Before returning from DoSomething1" to console
10. The `Task`, created in `Main()` completes, writing "Test!" to console.

So the "Test!" is in the end because your `Main()` returns `Task`. If you want the behaviour, you expect just swap `Task` to `void`:

```
public static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
}
```

Then when reaching the `await` operator, the `Main()` wont wait for the `Task()` completion and will continue the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Something worked like this..
You have to go through all function then back to where call await for it.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await DoSomething2();// <------ Start go to DoSomething2
            Console.WriteLine("Test!"); //F
            Console.ReadKey(); 
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething2"); // <------ A  godown
            var i = await DoSomething(); // <------ B  go to DoSomething
            Console.WriteLine("End DoSomething2");// <------ E  back to Main
        }

        public static async Task<int> DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething1");// <------ C godown
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("Before returning from DoSomething1");// <------ D back to DoSomething2
            return 88;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`await` and `async` **do stop** the execution of the code for you. But they actually do not stop the execution of the **main thread**.

In your example, everything looks like working as expected.

> Here as I understand, the execution should go on to execute statement C and D while awaiting DoSomething2()

No, they shouldn't because you said you want to **wait** till it is done. Even if it does not return something, it will wait because of `await`. Inside `DoSomething2()` you do the same thing.

`await` is more reasonable when you depend on the result of an asynchronous function. It saves you from callback hell.

Instead of this

[image]

you can use this

[image]

note: screenshots are from https://blog.hellojs.org/asynchronous-javascript-from-callback-hell-to-async-and-await-9b9ceb63c8e8 The codes are in JS.

Comment: Please convert the screenshorts to text as the links might break and consider exchanging the JS example with C# example since this is a question about C#

Answer (score 1):

As canbax already told in his answer the `await` operator does excatly what its naming suggests. It **A**synchronously **waits** that the Task (or better any type that can be [awaited](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-anything/)) completes.

So if you have code like

```
DoSomething1();
await DoSomething2Async();
DoSomething3();
```

the call to `DoSomething3` will only ocure after the task returned by the call to `DoSomething2Async` has finished with out errors, regardless of what happens in `DoSomething2Async`

In contrast you can creat a task by calling an async method and only later await the task, like:

```cs
DoSomething1();
Task task = DoSomething2Async();
DoSomething3();
await task;
```

this code is more open to the order of calling `DoSomething3` and the completion of the task. This is because you basicly tell the compiler "start doing `DoSomething2Async`, but I only care that it finishes after the call to `DoSomething3` has finished.

[Here](https://tio.run/##jZBBawIxEIXPm18x7Ck57ILucbFQ9NiCqNBD6WGIYQ26CWSiRcTfvk0aLSldpJDLvHkz75tIqqR1ahiOpE0H6zN51bcsr@rNzincBqHeIO2pZUwekAiWznYOe7iwgjx6LQHpbCREF7yiNpy8C2PvH4CuIxGNxcKuba/8LugTLtqg4CdqD5k@fY5rUjOTm6SEN7eG7EHVb0579aKN4mVVVeW9/TfihA58pJr9PydhxalQXdnPjSert/A7ghWXcarJN1M2nH3QCEjak4Kjp14dDecCZk8wsnxaCvEYrXmA1tzQrsPwBQ) is a live example for

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        DoSomething1();
        await DoSomething2Async();
        DoSomething3();

        Console.WriteLine("---");

        DoSomething1();
        var task = DoSomething2Async();
        DoSomething3();
        await task;
    }

    static void DoSomething1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    static async Task DoSomething2Async()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("2"));
    }

    static void DoSomething3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("3");
    }
}
```

which will mostlikly produce output like

```
1
2
3
---
1
3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with my code. Just as I described in the question, this code

```
statement1;
await statement2();
statement3;
statement4;
```

roughly equivalent to

```
statement1;
var awaiter = statement2().GetAwaiter();
awaiter.OnCompletion(() => {
    awaiter.GetResult();
    statement3;
    statement4;
});
```

This is true. So for the code

```
await DoSomething2(); // <------- B
Console.WriteLine("Test!"); // <------- C
Console.ReadKey(); // <------- D
```

it roughly equivalent to

```
statement1;
var awaiter = DoSomething2().GetAwaiter(); // <------- B
awaiter.OnCompletion(() => {
    awaiter.GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine("Test!"); // <------- C
    Console.ReadKey(); // <------- D
});
```

That is to say, the statement C & D will only execute after the task `DoSomething2()` completed. That's why `Test!` will only be printed at the end of the program. If I remove the `await` before `DoSomething2()`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadTesting
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoSomething2(); // <------- B (await removed)
            Console.WriteLine("Test!"); // <------- C
            Console.ReadKey(); // <------- D
        }

        public static async Task DoSomething2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething2"); 
            var i = await DoSomething(); // <------ A
            Console.WriteLine("End DoSomething2"); // <------ I
        }

        public static async Task<int> DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start DoSomething1");  // <------ E
            await Task.Delay(10000); // <------ F
            Console.WriteLine("Before returning from DoSomething1"); // <------ G
            return 88; // <------ H
        }
    }
}
```

The program will return this result:

```
Start DoSomething2
Start DoSomething1
Test!
Before returning from DoSomething1
End DoSomething2
```

This is reasonable and is exactly what I want. The execution logic can be logically understood as:

- Start at `main` and run `DoSomething2()`
- Go to `DoSomething2` and print "Start DoSomething2"
- Execute `DoSomething()` (statement A) and print "Start DoSomething1" (statement E)
- Execute `Task.Delay(10000)` (statement F). As it takes some time and returns a task (an awaitable), add the following statements (statement G & H) as a continuation (C1) and return to statement A.
- As statement A is an await statement, it adds the following statement (statement I) as a continuation (c2) and returns to statement B.
- The execution goes to B and the thread is not blocked. The code continue to execute statement C and D.
- Once statement F completed, the continuation C1 starts to execute.
- Once C1 completed, the continuation C2 starts to execute.

This is my understanding of the logic. Please correct me if you find any error. I'm new to asynchronous programming.

The misconception I have is that I though I have to await all async methods. This is not true.

Comment: If you call an async method without an await operator (and you can do that), you caller method doesn't have to be async at all. So you don't have to make Main() method async Task, you can just stick to good old public static void Main()

Comment: in such case, I think, more correct would be to make Main() async void, and call the inner async methods with await keyword. The result would be the same (it's actually just some syntactic shugar), but the code would be more understandable and transparent.